# Sort array (Time complexity )

Tags: arrays, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

if I have an array with cells 0-N that sorted, and cells N+1 until M+N, not sorted.
what will be the best time complexity to sort the array?

thanks!

---

Edit:

thanks !! If I want to do that in-place, it will change the complexity?

Comment: `O((m+n) log (m+n))`. If you use a standard library function, this bound is exact, and you can't get much better anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, sort just the M unsorted elements.  This takes time O(M log M) using a comparison-based sort (like quicksort, merge sort, or heap sort).

Then merge the two sorted segments (of lengths N and M) together.  This takes time O(M + N).

So the best time complexity, using a comparison-based sorted, is O(M + N + M log M).

Comment: M is the size of the unsorted part

Comment: Yes, I realized that I misread the problem and fixed my solution.

Comment: Note that `O(M + M log M)=O(M log M)`, meaning that you can simplify the complexity expression.

Comment: thanks !!
If I want to do that in-place, it will change the complexity?

Comment: If you can merge two sorted arrays in linear time and constant additional space, you won't change the complexity.  [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.88.1155) claims to describe such an algorithm, but I've only read the abstract.